# Android getting date

Tags: android, date

I am trying to use this code I found here on Stackoverflow. It seems to work for many people on Android because many people gave it thumbs up.

However, Eclipse will not let me run it even. It's giving me an error and saying that there is not an empty constructor for Date(). It has 3 other constructors that take arguments, but those seem to be for setting the new Date object to a specific time and date.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
```

Comment: Can your paste the logcat? I've used that before and it totally works. Also - pretty sure the other 3 constructors are depricated.

Comment: Also, When using the date and time for the filename, I had to using String.replaceAll(":", "") because the : is not allowed on the file system for all Android devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, Eclipse will not let me run it even. It's giving me an error
>   and saying that there is not an empty constructor for Date(). It has 3
>   other constructors that take arguments, but those seem to be for
>   setting the new Date object to a specific time and date.

Most likely it's is caused because you are imported **java.sql.date** but you need to use **java.util.date**

Look at reference of [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) and [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

Difference is that **java.sql.Date** has only two constructors with parameter(s) and **java.util.Date** also constructor(except others) without parameters - it you are looking for.

So change your import into:

```
import java.util.Date;
```

and now it will work.

Answer (score 0):

First Define a constant for the date format

```
public static final String DATE_FORMAT_TIMESTAMP = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
```

The below code will get you date and time stamp in the above format

```
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_TIMESTAMP);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            String TimeStampSTARTTIME = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
```